# HTTP Rewrite rule in IIS not activated

Tags: http, iis, url-rewriting

I have a web site like

> www.domainfullname.com

and I need to create a rule by which if I type

> www.domainname.com
>   or 
>   domainname.com

a redirect to www.domainfullname.com is activated.
So I tried to create a blank rule and set these parameters:
Pattern: *domainname.com*
Action - Rewrite URL: http:\\www.domainfullname.com\{R:1}
But it doesn't work. No redirect is happening. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Mistake 1 https://blog.lextudio.com/the-very-common-mistakes-when-using-iis-url-rewrite-module-a2ab7e4fee59

Answer (score 0):

You could use below URL rewrite rule:

```
 <rule name="redirect to sample 2 with www or non www" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="sample1.com|www.sample1.com" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern=".*" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.sample2.com/{R:1}" />
            </rule>
```

[image]
[image]

Note: if you want to rewrite the page you can change the action type to the rewrite.